# How can I have my script run certain days / months

Tags: python, selenium

I have just created a python script that automatically renews my pass. Is it possible to make the script run like a app or a background program to check if it is a certain day of a month and to run it?

Comment: Of course, it can. Python like other languages, which can do anything.

Comment: Are there any resources or keywords i should search up?

Comment: Instead of running it as a background program, use some sort of task scheduler to start the script at the right time. Like Windows Task Scheduler or cron on linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just scheduled task.

In your task call python.exe, pass your script as an argument and that's it.

Comment: that's exactly what i was looking for! Thanks!